# Using @AppStoarge with a custom object array does not persist data

Tags: swift, class, swiftui, appstorage

I am fairly new to SwiftUI and want to use the @AppStorage property wrapper to persist a list of custom class objects in the form of an array. I found a couple of posts here that helped me out creating the following generic extension which I have added to my AppDelegate:

```
extension Published where Value: Codable {
  init(wrappedValue defaultValue: Value, _ key: String, store: UserDefaults? = nil) {
    let _store: UserDefaults = store ?? .standard

    if
      let data = _store.data(forKey: key),
      let value = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Value.self, from: data) {
      self.init(initialValue: value)
    } else {
      self.init(initialValue: defaultValue)
    }

    projectedValue
      .sink { newValue in
        let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newValue)
        _store.set(data, forKey: key)
      }
      .store(in: &cancellableSet)
  }
}
```

This is my class representing the object:

```
class Card: ObservableObject, Identifiable, Codable{
    
    let id : Int
    let name : String
    let description : String
    let legality : [String]
    let imageURL : String
    let price : String
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws{
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CardKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        description = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .description)
        legality = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .legality)
        imageURL = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .imageURL)
        price = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .price)
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CardKeys.self)
        try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode(description, forKey: .description)
        try container.encode(imageURL, forKey: .imageURL)
        try container.encode(price, forKey: .price)
    }
    
    init(id: Int, name: String, description: String, legality: [String], imageURL: String, price : String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.legality = legality
        self.imageURL = imageURL
        self.price = price
    }
}

enum CardKeys: CodingKey{
    case id
    case name
    case description
    case legality
    case imageURL
    case price
}
```

I am using a view model class which declares the array as follows:

```
@Published(wrappedValue: [], "saved_cards") var savedCards: [Card]
```

The rest of the class simply contains functions that append cards to the array, so I do not believe they would be necessary to highlight here.

My problem is that during the runtime of the application everything seems to work fine - cards appear and are visible in the array however when I try to close my app and reopen it again the array is empty, and it seems like the data was not persisted. It looks like the JSONEncoder/Decoder is not able to serialize/deserialize my class, but I do not understand why.

I would really appreciate suggestions since I do not seem to find a way to solve this issue. I am also using the same approach with a regular Int array which works flawlessly, so it seems like there is a problem with my custom class.

Comment: This blog post from an ex-swiftui engineer at apple is the best solution I've found so far - https://nilcoalescing.com/blog/SaveCustomCodableTypesInAppStorageOrSceneStorage/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using `try? JSONDecoder().decode(Value.self, from: data)` and not `do/try/catch` you're missing the error that's happening in the JSON decoding. The encoder isn't putting in the `legality` key, so the decoding is failing to work. In fact, all of your types on `Codable` by default, so if you remove all of your custom Codable encode/decode and let the compiler synthesize it for you, it encodes/decodes just fine.

Example with @AppStorage:

```
struct Card: Identifiable, Codable{
    let id : Int
    let name : String
    let description : String
    let legality : [String]
    let imageURL : String
    let price : String
    
    init(id: Int, name: String, description: String, legality: [String], imageURL: String, price : String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.legality = legality
        self.imageURL = imageURL
        self.price = price
    }
}

enum CardKeys: CodingKey{
    case id
    case name
    case description
    case legality
    case imageURL
    case price
}

extension Array: RawRepresentable where Element: Codable {
    public init?(rawValue: String) {
        guard let data = rawValue.data(using: .utf8) else {
            return nil
        }
        do {
            let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([Element].self, from: data)
            print("Init from result: \(result)")
            self = result
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }

    public var rawValue: String {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self),
              let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        else {
            return "[]"
        }
        print("Returning \(result)")
        return result
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @AppStorage("saved_cards") var savedCards : [Card] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("add card") {
                savedCards.append(Card(id: savedCards.count + 1, name: "\(Date())", description: "", legality: [], imageURL: "", price: ""))
            }
            List {
                ForEach(savedCards, id: \.id) { card in
                    Text("\(card.name)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View model version with @Published (requires same Card, and Array extension from above):

```
class CardViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var savedCards : [Card] = Array<Card>(rawValue: UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "saved_cards") ?? "[]") ?? [] {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(savedCards.rawValue, forKey: "saved_cards")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = CardViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("add card") {
                viewModel.savedCards.append(Card(id: viewModel.savedCards.count + 1, name: "\(Date())", description: "", legality: [], imageURL: "", price: ""))
            }
            List {
                ForEach(viewModel.savedCards, id: \.id) { card in
                    Text("\(card.name)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your original @Published implementation relied on a `cancellableSet` that didn't seem to exist, so I switched it out for a regular @Published value with an initializer that takes the UserDefaults value and then sets UserDefaults again on `didSet`

Answer (score 1):

I recently made a wrapper around AppStorage for Codable values.  I'm posting it as an answer here because it's so simple, even though this is an old post. I didn't find much beside using RawRepresentable as above which gave me a BAD_EXEC error and seemed cumbersome.  Here is the new property wrapper.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
@propertyWrapper
struct CodableAppStorage<Value: Codable> : DynamicProperty {

    let defaultValue: Value
    private let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    private let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    @AppStorage private var data: Data

    public init(key: String, defaultValue: Value, store: UserDefaults? = nil ) {
        self.defaultValue = defaultValue
        let defaultData = (try? encoder.encode(defaultValue)) ?? Data()
        self._data = AppStorage(wrappedValue: defaultData, key, store: store )
    }

public init(wrappedValue defaultValue: Value, _ key: String, store: UserDefaults? = nil) {
    self.init(key: key, defaultValue: defaultValue, store: store)
    }

    public var wrappedValue: Value {
        get { (try? decoder.decode(Value.self, from: data)) ?? defaultValue }
    
        nonmutating set {
            if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(newValue) {
                data = encoded; debugPrint("\(newValue) saved")
            } else { debugPrint("Could not encode \(newValue)") }
        }
    }

    var projectedValue: Binding<Value> {
        Binding(
            get: { wrappedValue },
            set: { wrappedValue = $0 }
        )
    }

    func removeValue() { data.removeAll() }
}
```

Use it like @AppStorage

```
@CodableAppStorage("aCodable") var aCodable = MyCodable()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make a simple struct from your model like this:

```
struct Card : Codable  , Identifiable{
    let id : Int
    let name : String
    let description : String
    let legality : [String]
    let imageURL : String
    let price : String

            enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case id
                case name
                case description
                case legality
                case imageURL
                case price
            }
        }
```

then use jsonEncoder to get a json string out of your data like this

```
// Encode
let card = Card(id: 1, name: "AAA", description: "BBB" ....)

let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(card)
let json = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

and then simply persist it using :

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(json, forKey: "yourData")
```

when you want to observe and use it in UI u can use :

@AppStorage("yourData") var myArray: String = ""